# Advanced Role Base Access Control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authorization

Lets assume we have an application (similar to a crm) where vendors can manage its end-customers. Not only the vendor-employees can log in to the application, but also the end-customers as well (for self-administration purposes).

Therefore we have two dimensions of authorization:

- Vendor: can invoke functions regardless of the customerID and
- End-Customer: all function calls have to consider its customerID

The end-customer requirement is new:  currently the api is designed for Vendors only (without considering customerID context).

The authorization process untill now works like following:

On my controller i specify:

```
[MinimumRoleAuthorize(Role.Vendor)]
```

Therefore we have overwritten the HandleRequirementAsync from Authroizationhandler

```
 protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
            var role = await _userRoleRepository.GetRoleAsync(_claimsProvider.UserId);

            if (RoleMap.GetRoleFunc(requirement.Role)(role))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("User try to invoke a web method, which requires at least ... role.")
            }
    }
```

How would you design the controller/api with .Net Core in order to elegantly add the customerID context?

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some code you have

Comment: I just updated the post with some code from the current Authorization process.